# Symfony Angular No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, symfony

I have this error when I send post request to api symfony4 .. I use fosrestBundle for create api and nelmioCrosBundle for correcte error cros but also i have this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/user/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

code configuration nelmio:

```
nelmio_cors:
        #    defaults:
        #        origin_regex: true
        #        allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        #        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        #        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        #        max_age: 3600
        #    paths:
        #        '^/': ~
        paths:
            '^/api':
                allow_origin: ['*']
                allow_headers: ['Authorization', 'Content-Type']
                allow_methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
                max_age: 3600
```

and this is function to send data angular to symfony4:

```
uploadFiles(test) {
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token') });

      console.log(test);
      return this._http.post(this.url + '/user/upload',JSON.stringify(test) ,{ headers: headers })
        .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
    }
```

I use proxy but also error and also i create listener to set headers in response but also error.. how to resolve this error..

Answer (score 0):

Add `OPTIONS` to the `allow_methods`

Comment: @allow_methods in angular !!

Comment: No to the nelmio_cors config in Symfony. `allow_methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']`. Your browser does a preflight request to your API and it uses the OPTIONS http verb

Comment: Have your tried to allow all headers? `allow_headers: ['*']`

Comment: I'm not sure then. Clear your Symfony and browser cache, try a different browser, another machine... Let us know when you find

Answer (score 0):

'Authorization' header is not allowed by your backend. In your Symfony application you have to set a response header containing:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : 'Content-Type', 'Authorization'
```

Check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: but how to applique this !

Comment: You must try like this:

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\AcceptHeader;
    $acceptHeader = AcceptHeader::fromString($request->headers->get('Accept'));

I have fixed the same issue for Laravel and Angular. But I have no idea about symfony.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to play with bundles and don't need `CORS` you can disable it with this [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en). A green icon will appear with your enabled extensions, so you can uncheck the `Enable cross-origin sharing`

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in `allow_headers` array